# Target first and last items and append if greater than 2

Tags: templating, categories

I am trying to loop through a list of categories to add some text to the page. If it is the last item I want to replace the ',' with the words 'and' but only adda a ',' if there are more than 2 categories.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('products') %}
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ loop.last ? 'and ' }}{{ category.title }}{{ loop.index > 2 ? ', ' }}
{% endfor %}
```

if there is only category it would output:
hello

So if there are two categories it would output:
hello and world

if there are 3 or more it would output:
hello, world and space

My current code looks like this. but isn't quite working correctly.
Anyone able to help? or point in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would think of it is: I print the category title, then if this is not the last category I print the separator (`and` or `,`). I would use the [loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) `revindex` to distinguish the next-to-last category (which gets the `and`) from the others (which get the `,`). `loop.revindex` is like `loop.index` except that it counts the number of iterations from the end. So your code starts to look like this:

```
{% for category in categories %}
  {{category.title}}
  {% if not loop.last %}
    {{ loop.revindex == 2 ? ' and' : ',' }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That code will leave a space before the `,`, which you can fix by sticking everything on one line:

```
{% for category in categories %}
  {{category.title}}{% if not loop.last %}{{ loop.revindex == 2 ? ' and' : ',' }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Marion. I hadn't considered the revindex. This is useful.

Comment: I don't think I've every used revindex - but now I know what it's for!

Comment: First time I've heard of it, too!